# classic array vs std::array

Tags: c++, arrays

I try this simple program:

```
int* getElement(int arrayy[], int index) {
     return &arrayy[index];
}

int main() {

    int arrayy[4]{};

    *getElement(arrayy, 2)=50;

    std::cout << arrayy[2] << '\n';// here it prints 50 !

    return 0;
 }
```

`getElement()` will return the address of an element of my array through a pointer return, dereference it in the main and then change the value.

I want to do the same thing using `std::array`  in the place of classic array.

```
int* getElement(std::array<int, 4> arrayy, int index) {
    return &arrayy[index];
}

int main() {


    std::array<int, 4> arrayy{};

    *getElement(arrayy, 2)=50;

    std::cout << arrayy[2] << '\n';//here it prints 0 !

    return 0;
}
```

in the first it prints 50 and in the second 0 !

does `std::array` pass by value in calls ?

Comment: "does std::array pass by value in calls ?": Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of passing a pointer *by value*, the *pointed at* values are the same in the function and the call site. So the first program does what you expect.

---

In the second program, it's different because `std::array` has value semantics, so passing it *by value* means that you are passing a *copy* of all the underlying memory as well.

Note that in your code in the second program, the result of `0` is not guaranteed. You are returning a pointer to a value inside the copied `std::array` which will die when the function returns. This invokes undefined behavior.

If you want to get the same effect as the first program, you need to pass the `std::array` *by reference* instead:

```cpp
int* getElement(std::array<int, 4> &arrayy, int index) {
                                // ^  reference
    return &arrayy[index];
}
```

Comment: I thought that both `arrayy[]` and `std::array` were pointers inside calls,
the fact that both are arrays :p

Comment: No, only `array[]` decays to a pointer, `std::array` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

By default everything in C++ passes by value. Even your traditional array example passes a pointer by value. Of course you can use a pointer to change what it points at.

Your code actually has undefined behaviour because you are returning a pointer to the internals of an object which has been destroyed, namely the `arrayy` parameter of `getElement` which is destroyed when you exit the function.

If you want pass by reference you have to request it

```
int* getElement(std::array<int, 4>& arrayy, int index) {
    return &arrayy[index];
}
```

The `&` after the parameter type name makes all the difference.

Answer (score 1):

> does std::array pass by value in calls ?

Yes. The ability to do this (pass and return the object) is essentially the reason why std::array exists.

So, the function parameter is local to the function, and you return a pointer to this local object which becomes an invalid pointer as soon as the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Your code is just wrong, because you pass your `std::array` as value.

You would want to pass it by reference, like so:

```
int* getElement(std::array<int, 4> &arrayy, int index);
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux woops, yes my bad.